# PropTypes in chain of arrow functions

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to improve the quality of my app with PropTypes and I've stuck in this scenario:

```
const withLayout = (customProps) => (PageComponent) => (props) => {
    const { locale } = props.pageContext;
    const {
        localeKey, hideLangs, headerTitle, headerSubtitle, headerImages,
    } = customProps;
    ....
}
```

And this probably will not make any sense.

```
withLayout.propTypes = {
  pageContext: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

How can I assign PropTypes to this? Do I have to deconstruct it into three named functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this example will be helpful for you.

```
const withLayout = (customProps) => {
  const innerFunction = ( WrappedComponent ) => {
       const InnerComponent = ( props ) => <WrappedComponent { ...props } { ...customProps } />

       InnerComponent.propTypes = { /* ... */ }

       return InnerComponent
  }

  innerFunction.propTypes = { /* ... */ }

  return innerFunction
} 

withLayout.propTypes = { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Ok. So the only way to go is to deconstruct it into named functions (like withLayout and innerFunction in your example)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think with propTypes it's only way.